# Resampling a KDE (Kernel density estimation) in statsmodels

Tags: numpy, scipy, statsmodels

I am interested in using a sample of points to construct a KDE, and then using that KDE to resample points. `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` offers a very simple way to do this. For example, sampling from a gaussian distribution:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde, norm

sampled = np.random.normal(loc = 0, scale = 1, size = 1000)
kde = gaussian_kde(sampled, bw_method = 'silverman')
resampled = kde.resample(1000)
```

One flaw with `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde` is that it offers limited choices for bandwidth selection. Reading through [this](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/01/kernel-density-estimation/), I was pointed to `statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_density.KDEMultivariate` (more information [here](http://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_density.KDEMultivariate.html)). This lets me use cross validation to estimate the optimal bandwidth, which is more sophisticated if the underlying pdf you are trying to approximate is not unimodal. For example, using a sum of two gaussians, I can construct a KDE using `KDEMultivariate` as follows:

```
from statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_density import KDEMultivariate
sampled = np.concatenate((np.random.normal(loc = -3, scale = 1, size = 1000), \
                          np.random.normal(loc = 3, scale = 1, size = 1000)))
kde = KDEMultivariate(sampled, 'c', bw = 'cv_ml')
```

Exploring higher dimensional data with an arbitrary underlying pdf, it is clear that `KDEMultivariate` is able to produce a PDF that is much more representative of the original PDF. But there is a big issue I am running into -- `KDEMultivariate` has no `kde.resample()` method, and I am therefore unable to resample points from my new KDE. Is there a simple and efficient way to resample from a KDE constructed using `statsmodels.nonparametric.kernel_density.KDEMultivariate`?

Comment: After reading the source code of `resample()`, I think it's not very difficult to implement it to `KDEMultivariate`.

Comment: This is rather clumsy but I'd just use KDEMultivariate to estimate the bandwidth and then use that in a `gaussian_kde` instance.

Comment: The way scipy constructs the covariance matrix is fundamentally different than the way statsmodels constructs the covariance matrix. If I understand correctly, scipy has one bandwidth, which is multiplied by the data covaraince. This gives the same smoothing in all dimensions (scaled by the standard deviation of the data). In statsmodels, the bandwidth is an array, which corresponds to the SD of the gaussian kernels in each dimension. So you couldn't just pass the output of the bandwidth in statsmodels (which is an array) into the bandwidth argument of scipy (which is a number).

Answer (score 3):

Using motivation from `gaussian_kde` in `scipy`, I wrote a simple resampling procedure. In `statsmodels`, the bandwidth corresponds to the SD of the gaussian kernels in each dimension. In scipy, the bandwidth^2 is multiplied by the data covariance to construct the covariance matrix.

```
def resample(kde, size):
    n, d = kde.data.shape
    indices = np.random.randint(0, n, size)
    cov = np.diag(kde.bw)**2
    means = kde.data[indices, :]
    norm = np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(d), cov, size)
    return np.transpose(means + norm)
```

This takes an instance of `KDEMultivariate`, and resamples it by selecting random kernels, then sampling from those kernels using the fact that each kernel follows a multivariate normal distribution.